# US girlfriend wants to come back to the UK this year even though she's been for six months already

Tags: uk, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

my name is Darren and I am wondering if you could help me. I have been in a online relationship with a US girl for the past ten weeks. We've been skyping non-stop since we met so I'd like to meet her now. Before we started to date she had been in the UK for six months back in January 2016.

We started to talk back in July and she has a return ticket to the UK this September 30th although we've decided not to use that as it's to an airport miles away from me. We will buy her a return ticket to the US. I'm concerned that she has been in the UK too long this year and that she could be refused entry due to the immigration officer not believing she is a genuine visitor even though we have plans to go places throughout her time here.

We both wanted her to come for six months although now we're thinking three months. My personal concern is this quote “Genuine intention to visit; (b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home". And also "must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit " although I will be supporting her while she stays with me. I am on Personal Independence Payment and Employment and support allowance.

Is it correct if she is refused she'll get a black X stamp in her passport and then she'd have to keep applying for a visa? Also would she have to pay for the return flight back to her home?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you "want to meet now" I suggest 1 or 2 weeks, and if it is easier, visit her country instead of a 3 or 6 month committment. I do see one disadvantage of my suggestion, that 1 or 2 weeks may not be enough to distinguish carnal pleasures from emotional and intellectual compatibility. Is this even the right forum for your question?

Comment: @WeatherVane the question appears to be about immigration control for visitors and the limitations associated with that status; the OP is not asking for advice about how to evaluate the relationship.  So yes, it appears to be the right forum for the question.

Comment: @quackstar84 - your timings are unclear. You talk of a six month visit 'back in January 2016'. Is that starting or ending in Jan 2016? You're also talking about 'in the UK too long this year'. Is that another visit, or should 2016 be 2017? Why does your girlfriend already have a ticket for 30th September? Two lengthy visits in a short space of time will certainly set alarm bells ringing for the ECO. I might also question the motives of this girl in engaging in her relationship with you.

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean by a "return" ticket: do you mean a there-and-back ticket [UK definition], or a single leg get-back ticket [US definition]?. Whichever you mean, how is replacing a "return ticket to the UK" with a "return ticket to the US" supposed to make sense? I am also confused as how someone on benefits is going to be able to support someone else for 6 months... either you're deluded or the benefits system is giving you significantly more money than it needs to.